# Store list of directory as an Array from listbox

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

am a newbie in VB.NET and just managed to get the list of my files into listbox. but how do i add same into array ? i mean instead of listbox add into array.

```
    Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetFiles("c:\users\phnagarajappa\desktop", "178845_M6E*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Dim dir As String
    For Each dir In dirs

        ListBox1.Items.Add(dir)

        ' MsgBox(dir)
    Next
```

Comment: In your code dirs is an array

Comment: You dont need that loop: `ListBox1.Items.AddRange(dirs)`

Comment: got the solution thanks for that.

Comment: @VijayPenny Post your solution as an answer and accept your own answer so other people can learn.